# Website Gallery not responsive

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, gallery

I am doing a responsive website that contains a gallery page. Here the gallery page is not responsive for mobile phones less than 5" screen. In these screens the images not fits to the screen. Is there any solution.
Link : http://www.wheelfix.ae/test-2/

Comment: sure there are several solutions, what have you tried?

Comment: which plugin that u are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Media query with `max-width: 650px`.
In the media query set the width to 100% and the height to auto.

I am not Sure if this solves your Problem but i think it is.